# JSON schema - support regular expression for field

Tags: json, jsonschema

I want to use the following library `gojsonschema` to validate json structure,
Currenlty I've two questions to the example below

https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema

1. what is the `#/definitions/....` and what is the purpose of it?
2. the name should have the following:

`{required: true, unique: true, pattern: '/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+$/'}`

The unique is that if I've another name filed in the schema it should be unique, How can I validate it with jsonschema?

```
var schema = `
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "name": ...
    "properties": {
        "username": {"$ref": "#/definitions/name"},
```

**update**

what I found is this
https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html

But how should I check it inside the json i've provided

should It be like this

```
var schema = `
    {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "type": "object",
        "name": {
        "type": "object",
        "pattern":'/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+$/'
}

        "properties": {
            "username": {"$ref": "#/definitions/name"},
```

Comment: So, you [have searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=json+schema+rfc), found [the JSON schema site](http://json-schema.org/), read through the docs and examples on it, right? If not, please do.

Comment: @kostix - Thanks for the tip :) , Im struggling to add regular expression condition to the jsonschema ? can you assist ?

Comment: check my answer, that should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation/?include_text=1

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {  
        "username": {  
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "/^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+$/"
            },
            "uniqueItems": true
         }
    },
    "required": [  
         "username"
    ]
}
```

1:    The "definitions" keywords provides a standardized location for
   schema authors to inline re-usable JSON Schemas into a more general
   schema.  The keyword does not directly affect the validation result.

This keyword's value MUST be an object.  Each member value of this
   object MUST be a valid JSON Schema.

As an example, here is a schema describing an array of positive
   integers, where the positive integer constraint is a subschema in
   "definitions":

```
  {
   "type": "array",
   "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/positiveInteger" },
   "definitions": {
       "positiveInteger": {
           "type": "integer",
           "exclusiveMinimum": 0
       }
   }
   }
```

2:  uniqueItems

The value of this keyword MUST be a boolean.

If this keyword has boolean value false, the instance validates
   successfully.  If it has boolean value true, the instance validates
   successfully if all of its elements are unique.

Omitting this keyword has the same behavior as a value of false.

---

required

The value of this keyword MUST be an array.  Elements of this array,
   if any, MUST be strings, and MUST be unique.

An object instance is valid against this keyword if every item in the
   array is the name of a property in the instance.

Omitting this keyword has the same behavior as an empty array.

---

properties

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "progBinaryName": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9 -_]+_Prog\\.(exe|EXE)$"
    }
}
}
```

The value of "properties" MUST be an object.  Each value of this
   object MUST be a valid JSON Schema.

This keyword determines how child instances validate for objects, and
   does not directly validate the immediate instance itself.

Validation succeeds if, for each name that appears in both the
   instance and as a name within this keyword's value, the child
   instance for that name successfully validates against the
   corresponding schema.

Omitting this keyword has the same behavior as an empty object.

Comment: Thanks 1+ , how should I use the regular expression for name?  can you please provide example ?

Answer (score 2):

1. `#/definitions/name` is an [internal reference](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.9.2.1) to another schema.  The document should have section that looks like the following that is being referenced:

   ```
   "definitions": {
       "name": {
            ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. JSON schema does not have a `unique` validator.  There is a [uniqueItems](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.4.5) validator that can be used with arrays but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks 1+ , how should I use the regular expression for name?  can you please provide example ?

Comment: @07_05_GuyT did you get any solution. I need to use regex at "name" too.. Obj key dynamic so I have to use regex"environment_variables": {
        "type": "object",
         "properties": {
                "^[a-z]+$": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "^[a-z]+$"
            ]
        }